# Radiation efficiency of patch antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, antennas

The figure 2.54 is taken from the textbook Jean-Marc Laheurte, Christian Ripoll, Dominique Paret, Christophe Loussert, “UHF RFID Technologies for Identification and Traceability”, 2014, John Wiley & Sons. It says radiation efficiency of patch antenna increases for higher substrate thickness. But the figure 1  taken from David M. Pozar, Daniel H. Schaubert - Microstrip Antennas_ The Analysis and Design of Microstrip Antennas and Arrays (1995, Wiley-IEEE Press) shows that efficiency decreases for higher substrate thickness. How do we interpret the two graphs with respect to efficiency? Does efficiency increases or reduces?

[image: Figure 2.54]

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Is the substrate material and frequency range the same for the two references?

Comment: @JonCuster For figure 2.54 the substrate is a type of PET plastic, whose electric properties are εr = 2.62, tanδ = 6.84×.0-3. Nothing is mentioned in Fig.1. It is just an explanation for a general case. My question was also in general how do we say the efficiency varies? Whether it increases or decreases wrt height of substrate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is still open, but maybe there are also some other people interested in the answer:

If you do some simulations then you will see that increasing the substrate height leads to a reduced efficiency. The efficiency itself is a combination of the losses in the substrate, losses of the copper, and the radiation efficiency. As we don't know if the efficiency mentioned by Pozar includes all of the definitions it could already give an answer.

Another assumption from my side would be that by increasing the substrate height more and more the fields in the substrate get less and therefore the patch radiates more. But I don't know if the pattern is then still the same. However, increasing the permittivity again leads to a more concentrated field in the substrate and therefore more losses which are reducing the efficiency again.

Let me know what you think about the idea!